# Does Java's BufferedReader.readLine() put the whole file in memory?

Tags: java, file, io, bufferedreader

Does it? Or maybe only separate strings are put on each readline() and maximal space of memory taken is volume for the longest string?

Comment: It fills its buffer from the file. It doesn't read the whole file at once (unless the file is smaller than the buffer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it?

No.

> Or maybe only separate strings are put on each readline()

No.

> and maximal space of memory taken is volume for the longest string?

No.

It's a buffered reader. That means it has a buffer. It fills the buffer, to the extent of available data and its own limit, which is or was 4096 characters. It scans the buffer for a line terminator; returns the data before it as the next line; and deletes it from the buffer. When the buffer is empty it fills it again.

What the caller does with each `readLine()` result is up to the caller.

Comment: [Was](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/BufferedReader.java#88). It's now 8192.